# Which documentation package more actively maintained: NaturalDocs or RoboDoc?

Tags: documentation, tcl

I am documenting a small itcl project.  Due to shortcomings in itcl support in doxygen, and the fact that Ruff! does not support itcl, I am left with NaturalDocs and RoboDoc as the leading candidates.  However, I don't want to pick an unsupported system, and was wondering which is going to be there in the long term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will be there in the long term? Who knows! It depends on how much people use it, really, as with all open source code systems. It should be noted that both the tools you refer to are really slow developing at this point: they do what they do and need little significant change to keep on doing it.

As far as I can see, [ROBODoc](http://rfsber.home.xs4all.nl/Robo/index.html) requires that you do pretty much all the annotation work yourself, whereas [NaturalDocs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) will derive a bit more for you. Not very much though; in particular, you will have to write plenty of annotations on things whichever route you use. (I've no particular experience with either though; I tend to prefer to maintain documentation in a separate file with something like [doctools](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3054) but that's a very different approach. I've also done nasty custom things in the past; you *really* don't want to use them.)

Comment: For what it's worth, the author of Natural Docs just recently (August 2017) released a massive overhaul and update (ditched Perl and rewrote in C#). He seems to have set himself up for light to moderate continued development, with a concrete plan for future releases.